# CSS top property with percentage value not working

Tags: html, css

**CSS:**

```
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 200px);
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="background"></div>
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="header"><label>A+ CMS</label></div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image]

The `left` property has works properly, but `top` property doesn't. I set 50% to `top` but the word "A+ CMS" keeps hang on the top of the screen.
If I change the value of `top` from percentage to `px`, it works. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because it's 10% from the top of the its container, which currently is the height of the text so it's not moving.

If you add a height property to the container the top property will work. Here's an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/bncteqzv/

```css
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: calc(50% - 200px);
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
}

.test {
    height: 500px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="test" style="position: relative">
    <div class="header"><label>A+ CMS</label></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want my outer div match the screen size, I set height to 100% but doesn't works, any method?

Comment: There are many approaches to this. This thread might prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/4933483

Answer (score 0):

Give height to .container class div

```css
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 200px);
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
}
.container {
    height: 500px; 
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="header"><label>A+ CMS</label></div>
</div>
```